# Regular Expression to match multiple groups

Tags: c++, regex, c++11

I'm trying to write a regular expression to match strings containing two different groups of hexadecimal numbers 4 characters in length, separated by a hyphen. e.g.

> 00AA-10F2
>   14ED-7F09
>   1A20-A55F

This expression works ok,

```
[0-9A-F]{4}-[0-9A-F]{4}
```

but I was wondering if there's a more concise way of achieving the same thing.

I'm using C++11 `std::regex` (currently in default / ECMAScript mode) in case that makes a difference.

Any advice would be really appreciated!

Thanks,

Rich.

Comment: No, there is no other way with `std::regex`. Of course, you may build the pattern dynamically by using a variable holding `[0-9A-F]{4}` but I doubt it makes sense for this pattern.

Comment: In some other environments you could use something like `([0-9A-F]{4})-(?1)` to re-use the first half of the pattern, but this doesn't work with `std::regex` as Wiktor said. Why do you want to make it shorter though ? I'm curious.

Comment: I know you can use capture groups in cases where the string has identical parts e.g. `([0-9A-F]{4})-\1` would match 00AA-00AA.I was just curious to see if the same was true of the expression itself. Thanks for your comments!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really. You could write expressions like

```
([0-9A-F]{4}-?){2}
```

or

```
(-?[0-9A-F]{4}){2}
```

But the former would also match strings like `00AA-10F2-`, `00AA10F2-` and the latter would also match `-00AA-10F2` and `-00AA10F2`. There is no shorter way to write the regular expression `[0-9A-F]{4}-[0-9A-F]{4}`.

You could however use plain C++ tricks like:

```
std::string subexpression("[0-9A-F]{4}");
std::regex regularExpression(subexpression + "-" + subexpression);
```

Alternatively, modes other than the default ECMAScript mode may provide regular expressions syntax which allows certain subexpressions to be repeated, but support other modes in C++ implementations may be lacking.